# setRowData() method of ag_grid_angular object is rendering data in wrong order in the user interface though it takes data in correct order as input

Tags: sorting, ag-grid-angular

setRowData() method of ag_grid_angular object is rendering data in wrong order in the user interface though it takes the data in correct order as input.
This is happening for the column which is listing name of the object and this is not happening for the column which lists the last modified date of the object.

I am using below code snippet
public rowData:[]
rowData value is assigned from an API output & contains values for many columns.

gridObj.setRowData(rowData)

I tried to render data with many columns in the ag_grid_angular object using it's setRowData() method.
I expected the setRowData() method should render the data in the user interface in the order which is given as input to it.

But, the setRowData() method is rendering data in wrong order and the rendering order is not matching with the order in the input.